# Create a UINavigationBar without using [Projectname]AppDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create another UINavigationBar in my project, but it seems that I'm missing some key detail. When the application first loads, it does have it's own navigation system, but now I'm trying to add another navigation to a **modal**.

Many tutorials show you need to connect the view to the [self window], which only seems to work in the AppDelegate files, but when I've tried placing the code* in *viewDidLoad*, I can never seem to build without any errors.

I've seen this in multiple apps, but how is this done (programmatically or with IBuilder)?
Thanks!

Example code I've tried in *viewDidLoad*

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:[self viewController]]; 
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show enough code to be able to understand how you do it, but it seems to me that you are showing a controller modally, then trying to add as a subview to its view a navigation controller.

You can try and directly push modally your navigation controller (from your app delegate or where it makes sense for your app):

```
(IBAction) navigateToSecondaryViewController {
     if (secondaryViewController == nil) {
         informationTableViewController = [[SecondaryViewController alloc]
                initWithNibName:@"SecondaryViewController" 
                bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
         secondaryViewController.delegate = self;
      }

     if (navController == nil) {
           navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
           initWithRootViewController:secondaryViewController];
     }

     [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

 }
```

[Full example here](http://diaryofacodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/uinavigationcontroller-as-modal-view.html).

Comment: This worked almost perfectly! Just needed to change the first if statement a bit.